# Create a circular Progress Bar using tailwind css in react

Tags: css, tailwind-css

After searching for a way to create a Progress Bar using tailwind css in react
I found the following [solution](https://play.tailwindcss.com/OObPqXeFsK):

```js
.progress-ring__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 400, 400;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.35s;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}



<div class="relative w-40 h-40">
  <svg class="w-full h-full" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <!-- Background circle -->
    <circle
      class="text-gray-200 stroke-current"
      stroke-width="10"
      
      cx="50"
      cy="50"
      r="40"
      fill="transparent"
    ></circle>
    <!-- Progress circle -->
    <circle
      class="text-indigo-500  progress-ring__circle stroke-current"
      stroke-width="10"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      cx="50"
      cy="50"
      r="40"
      fill="transparent"
      stroke-dashoffset="calc(400 - (400 * 45) / 100)"
    ></circle>
    
    <!-- Center text -->
    <text x="50" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="12" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle">70%</text>

  </svg>
</div>
```

**It works well**
But I did not understand the idea of ​​how to calculate the percentage

```js
 stroke-dasharray: 400, 400;
 stroke-dashoffset="calc(400 - (400 * 45) / 100)"
```

**What is meant by stroke-dashoffset, stroke-dasharray and how to assign percentage to it?**

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **stroke-dasharray**

The stroke-dasharray attribute controls the lengths of the dashes and gaps between them. It is a list of comma and/or whitespace-separated numbers that declare the lengths of the alternating dashes and gaps.

For example, stroke-dasharray: 10, 5 would create a dashed line with dashes of length 10 units and gaps of length 5 units.

In your code, stroke-dasharray: 400, 400; means that the dashed line has a dash length of 400 units and a gap of 400 units. Since the circle's perimeter is likely less than 400, this results in a line that looks solid because the dash fills the entire circle. Try playing with those values to see what it does exactly.

### **stroke-dashoffset**

The stroke-dashoffset attribute specifies the distance into the dash pattern to start the dash. For example, if the stroke-dasharray is "10,5", setting stroke-dashoffset to 5 will make the dash pattern start in the middle of a gap.

### **Calculating Percentage**

The formula for the stroke-dashoffset you've mentioned, calc(400 - (400 * 45) / 100), calculates where the dash pattern should start based on a percentage.

The 400 in stroke-dasharray: 400, 400; sets the dash and gap to be 400 units each, so it appears as a solid circle.

The calc(400 - (400 * 45) / 100) for stroke-dashoffset calculates the starting point of the dash pattern based on 45%. This effectively "removes" 45% of the dash, making it look as if 45% of the circle is filled in.

**So, the formula for assigning percentage P would be:**

```
stroke-dashoffset="calc(400 - (400 * P) / 100)";
```